# Dataframe is empty after merging two dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes in which I am trying to merge using `pandas`. One table is 4 columns and the other one is 3. I am attempting an inner join on an int64 type column.
[image: Picture showing datatypes]

On the link you can see both columns named UPC are int64 types.

Just to make sure the Dataframes weren't empty, I have added a picture of the first 20 rows for each table.

[image: table sample]

when I try to merge I put the following command.

```
result = merge(MPA_COMMODITY, MDM_LINK_VIEW, on='UPC')
```

When I try to check the return value, it returns the column names but it says that the Dataframe is empty.

[image: Saying Dataframe is empty]

This is using Python 3.6.4 and Pandas version 0.22.0.

If there is any other information needed please let me know. More than glad to update post if have to.

Comment: Merging defaults to an inner join, i.e. the result only contains the keys from the `UPC` column that appear in _both_ data frames.  Try using `how="outer"`, at least for debugging, to see whether you will get a non-empty result.

Comment: Thank you! Will try that and give back results!

Comment: @SvenMarnach it seems to be that the table just didnt have good data to join on a key. I appreciate the help and it seems that the data I got just wasnt correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
MPA_COMMODITY.merge(MDM_LINK_VIEW, on='UPC')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: `pandas.merge(A, B, ...)` should be equivalent to `A.merge(B, ...)`, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html.